# Linking two pages with a button in Blend

Tags: c++, xaml, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'm using Blend for Visual Studio 2012 and I'm making a Windows Store App with XAML and C++. I've designed a variety of pages of content for my app and I have a user interface for the buttons and controls. How would I go about linking two of these pages with a button? I can't seem to find the appropriate property in the 'properties' tab. In 'event' mode, 'click' is completely greyed out, as well as the other events. If it is something I would have to code, would that code go in the page's XAML file or C++ file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 Just stumbled over the same problem. I realize that this is an old question, but I feel that other users might benefit from it, as blend's behavior for c++ deviates in unintuitive ways from its behavior for c#